# How to make an array of linked lists, whose list points to a matrix row in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a type:

```
typedef struct node
{
    double data;
    struct node * next;
}NODE;
```

which represents a linked list node.

I have a function:

```
void add(NODE ** head, double data)
{
    NODE * new = NULL;
    new = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->next = NULL;
    new->data = data;
    if(* head == NULL) * head = new;
    else
    {
        NODE * temp = NULL;
        for(temp = * head; temp->next; temp = temp->next);
        temp->next = new;
    }
}
```

which adds a new number at the end of the list.

I need to write a function (using the function 'add') to form and return a dynamically allocated array of 'n' linked lists (every element of the array points to the first node of the list) based on a matrix of dimensions 'nxm', where the elements of the k-th list should correspond to the elements of the k-th order of the matrix.

Function prototype:

```
NODE ** mat2arr(double ** matrix, int n, int m)
```

where 'matrix' represents array of pointers, n number of rows and m number of columns.

I tried it like this but it gives me segmentation errors. How can i fix the code or rewrite it with new ideas, also how could i access the returned array of linked lists so i can print the values ?

```
NODE ** mat2arr(double ** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    NODE ** array_list = NULL;
    array_list = malloc(n * sizeof(NODE *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        NODE * list = NULL;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            add(&list, matrix[i][j]);
        array_list[i] = list;
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Calling the function mat2arr:

```
NODE ** array_list = NULL;
array_list = mat2arr(matrix, n, m);
//matrix represents a 2D array, a matrix
```

Comment: To clarify your goal, it seems like you want a sparse/variable dimension 2D array of `double`??? If so, a linked list [as you've defined it] has a `next` pointer for each data cell--this is very wasteful. So, I'm assuming you want the 2D array as I first described [your 2nd code block] but the code is broken? That is, you don't [really] need the `NODE` struct but more like: `typedef struct { int width; int height; double *data } ARRAY;` for variable dimensions that are _fixed_ when the array is created?

Comment: Or, do you need to have the length/count of _each_ row be variable and independent, such as: `typedef struct { int width; double *data; } ROW;  typedef struct { int height; ROW *rows; } ARRAY;` where you can add/delete rows anytime and can grow/shrink any [given] row independently of the length of any other row???

Comment: @CraigEstey This was my exam task, as I understood I need to make a separate linked list for every row in the matrix. Then I need to point to every linked list using the array of lists. I cant change the type definition I need to use it as it is.

Comment: Okay, sort of ... Consider a normal 2D array: `double myarray[5][3]`. Getting the address of a _row_ `i` is: `double *rowptr = myarray[i]`. But, for a linked list of _rows_, finding a row is the LL traversal [which is slow]. But, okay. Your LL is _not_ a linked list of _rows_, it is a LL of data _cells_. You probably want: `struct rowptr { double *data; struct rowptr *next; };` Note that `data` is `double *` and _not_ merely `double` as you have it.

Comment: So, I'm skeptical about the node definition as shown. Is the exact text of the problem statement available [i.e. _edit_ your question and post it]?

Comment: @CraigEstey First of all thanks for sticking for a while, second i can't change my struct type as it was an exam task and i wanted to do it at home so optimizing the type and function definition isn't possible (this code wont be used in software), third what i understood this function should do is, with the matrix that is given myarray[5][3], to make also a matrix but with using linked list. The first basis should be a linked list of rows which is made using the 'add' function for every 'j-th' element of the 'm-th' collumn and then i should make an array of linked lists of 'n-th' rows.

Comment: Hmm, based on that, and your `struct` definition, we'd have: `typedef struct element { double data; struct element *next; } ELEMENT;  typedef struct { int height; ELEMENT *rows; } ARRAY;` That is, a 1D _array_ of pointers to linked lists for the rows (i.e. one linked list for each row). But, your last comment says that instead of indexing into an array, you have a linked list for each dimension. You can't do that with the given struct. You'd need: `typedef struct element { double data; struct element *next; } ELEMENT;  typedef struct rowlist { ELEMENT *rows; struct rowlist *next; } ARRAY;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    double data;
    struct node * next;
}NODE;

NODE * add(NODE * head, double data)
{
    NODE * new = NULL;
    new = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->next = NULL;
    new->data = data;
    if( head == NULL) {
        head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        NODE * temp = head;
        while( temp->next) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new;
    }
    return head;
}

NODE ** mat2arr ( int n, int m, double **matrix)
{
    NODE ** array_list = NULL;
    array_list = calloc(n, sizeof(NODE *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            array_list[i] = add(array_list[i], matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return array_list;
}

int main ( void) {
    double **myArray = NULL;
    NODE ** array_list = NULL;

    myArray = calloc ( sizeof *myArray, 5);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        myArray[i] = calloc ( sizeof **myArray, 3);
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            myArray[i][j] = ( i + 1) * ( j + 1);
        }
    }

    array_list = mat2arr( 5, 3, myArray);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        NODE * each = array_list[i];
        while ( each) {
            printf ( "data %f\n", each->data);
            each = each->next;
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        NODE * each = array_list[i];
        while ( each) {
            NODE *temp = each;
            each = each->next;
            free ( temp);
        }
        free ( myArray[i]);
    }
    free ( array_list);
    free ( myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think i misrepresented the definition of the matrix by trying to make it simpler. The matrix represents a double pointer 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    double data;
    struct node * next;
}NODE;

void add(NODE ** head, double data)
{
    NODE * new = NULL;
    new = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->next = NULL;
    new->data = data;
    if(* head == NULL) * head = new;
    else
    {
        NODE * temp = NULL;
        for(temp = * head; temp->next; temp = temp->next);
        temp->next = new;
    }
}

NODE ** mat2arr(double ** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    NODE ** array_list = NULL;
    array_list = malloc(n * sizeof(NODE *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        NODE * list = NULL;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            add(&list, matrix[i][j]);
        }
        array_list[i] = list;
    }
    return array_list;
}

void delete_list(NODE ** head)
{
    while(* head)
    {
        NODE * temp = (* head)->next;
        free(* head);
        * head = temp;
    }
}

void main()
{
    printf("Input matrix 2x3: \n");
    double ** matrix = NULL;
    matrix = malloc(2 * sizeof(double *));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        double * array = NULL;
        array = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Matrix[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%lf", &array[j]);
        }
        matrix[i] = array;
    }
    NODE ** array_list = NULL;
    array_list = mat2arr(matrix, 2, 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        NODE * temp = NULL;
        temp = array_list[i];
        while(temp)
        {
            printf("%lf ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        delete_list(&array_list[i]);
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    free(array_list);
}
```